# In Angular 7 how can avoid project page reload inside of profile page navigate to login page?

Tags: angular, router

When I login to the dashboard and refresh the page redirected to Login page because I added the router guard. I want to avoid that redirected inside of that dashboard page. Is there any way to do that ?

This is the structure of my router guard

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          this.router.navigate(['/userlogin']);
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
    );
  }
```

My routering look like below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '' , component : AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
     }
  {path: 'userlogin' , component: UserloginComponent},

  { path: 'admin' , 
    component : AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
     }]
```

Comment: What does your route structure look like?

Comment: @Will Taylor I added both routing and router guard structure

Comment: I expect `isLoggedIn` is returning false on page reload. You need to execute some kind of process to check whether the user is authenticated when the app first loads, before you check `authService.isLoggedIn`. How you do that will depend on how your authentication works.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in, you need to save the user token to the localStorage and save this information to your guard, so every call to the backend you send the jwt token from localStorage.
What is happening is, if you do not say to your guard you are logged in, them isLoggedIn will be false and will redirect you.
Put this in your guard constructor:

```
this.localStorage.observe('session')
            .subscribe(loggedIn => Object.assign(this._loggedIn, loggedIn || {}));
```

And when you log in put this:

```
this.localStorage.store('session', this._loggedIn);
```

`localStorage` is a private var from `LocalStorageService` (ngx-webstorage), you can use whatever you want.